# Connecting to soap wsdl service

Tags: soap, wsdl

I'm trying to connect to soap wsdl service, but it doesn't work, I keep getting 415 error - Unsupported Media Type. I cannot use things like SoapUI directly, as only way how to connect to the service is via linux server and client certificate must be used. I have wsdl and xsd files and used SoapUI to generate headers and dotnet-svcutil to generate content.

My question is: What am I doing wrong with headers? At least I assume 415 should be an issue with headers.

```
'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
'SOAPaction: "calculate"',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($input_xml),
'Host: <url>:443',
'Connection: Keep-Alive',
'User-Agent: CURL-HttpClient',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if your SOAP service is 1.1 or 1.2. But, For SOAP 1.2, `Content-type` should be `Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset="***"`. While in case SOAP 1.1, it was `text/xml`. SO it might be the issue.

SOAP 1.2 e.g. `Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset="utf-8"`

SO, I think your issue may be with Content-type values as it displays, `text/xml`.

Comment: I've edited content type, but the error is still there. Do you think it could indicate invalid content (invalid soap that I send via the post request)? Does url where I send post requests change if I use different action?